# MongoDB sharding, any bottleneck at 'mongos' the MongoDB router?

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, sharding

To increase performance for MongoDB, sharding the database is rather necessary. However, all connections and queries go through a 'mongos' (MongoDB router).

The MongoDB router is the only one in the sharding architecture, could that be a bottleneck and break down the whole sharded cluster?

Comment: A sharded cluster can have multiple `mongos`s. So, in case a `mongos` is not available the application driver automatically connects to the cluster with another `mongos`.

Comment: In particular, you could run a mongos locally on each node that needs to talk to mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The MongoDB router is the only one in the sharding architecture

You can (and should) run multiple `mongos` nodes. `mongos` can be colocated on the servers that run `mongod`s, and in fact this is a common deployment strategy, because `mongos` have relatively low resource requirements. That said, if the server overall is experiencing resource issues (for example, high network load, or a large number of files open), then `mongos` could be affected even though the load may have originated elsewhere (such as in the `mongod` running on the same machine).

> could that be a bottleneck

`mongos` is generally quite efficient, though you should test it for your particular requirements.

> and break down the whole sharded cluster?

A single `mongos` instance *is* a single point of failure, which is why a production deployment should have multiple `mongos` instances running.

Comment: tks, i have multiple mongos now, hm, should work :)